# Entity Framework 6 Database First Not fetching data

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, unity-container

I am developing a Angular 2 application using web api and entity framework to fetch data from sql server database. Currently there are records in the customer table but the entity framework doesn't seem like to create and initializing the context properly. When I debug the **`CustomerDao`** class that contains **`GetAllCustomers()`** method and look into the Customers entity in the **`CustomerOrderContext`** object, I see a message:

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of the object"
```

The stacktrace shows me the message below

```
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

Please see the code below

**CustomerDao**

```
IEnumerable<CustomerOrder.BusinessObjects.Customer> ICustomerDao.GetAllCustomers()
        {
            using (var customerOrderContext = new Entities())
            {
                return (from customer in customerOrderContext.Customers

                        select new CustomerOrder.BusinessObjects.Customer
                        {
                            Id = customer.Id,
                            FirstName = customer.FirstName,
                            LastName = customer.LastName,
                            Address = customer.Address,
                            City = customer.City,
                            Email = customer.Email,
                            Gender = customer.Gender,
                            State = customer.State,
                            Zip = customer.Zip
                        }).ToList();
            }
        }
```

**The context class**

```
 public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities()
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Please note I have the connection string in my web.config file
For e.g `<add name="Entities"`

**CustomerOrder.BusinessObjects**

```
namespace CustomerOrder.BusinessObjects
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }

        public int? Zip { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Customer class in the context**

```
 public partial class Customer
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Customer()
        {
            this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Zip { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

A additional information, I have also implemented dependency injection using unity container.

Below is the structure of my solution

CustomerOrder.Business.Objects CustomerOrder.Data.Objects (references the business object) CustomerOrder.Service.Api (references business object and service implementation) CustomerOrder.Service.Implementation (references business objects and data objects) CustomerOrder.Web (Yet to implement)

**Unity.Config.cs**

```
 public static class UnityConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            // register all your components with the container here
            // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

            // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();

            container.RegisterType<ICustomerProvider, CustomerProvider>();
            container.RegisterType<IOrderProvider, OrderProvider>();
            container.RegisterType<IProductProvider, ProductProvider>();
            container.RegisterType<IDaoFactory, DaoFactory>();

            container.RegisterType<ICustomerDao, CustomerDao>();
            container.RegisterType<IOrderDao, OrderDao>();
            container.RegisterType<IProductDao, ProductDao>();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        }
    }
```

**CustomerOrder.Data.Objects**

```
  public class DaoFactory : IDaoFactory
    {
        public DaoFactory(ICustomerDao CustomerDao, IProductDao ProductDao, IOrderDao OrderDao)
        {


            this.CustomerDao = CustomerDao;
            this.OrderDao = OrderDao;
            this.ProductDao = ProductDao;
        }

        public ICustomerDao CustomerDao { set; get; }

        public IOrderDao OrderDao { set; get; }

        public IProductDao ProductDao { set; get; }



    }
```

**CustomerOrder.Service.Implementation project**

```
public class CustomerProvider : ICustomerProvider
    {

        private readonly IDaoFactory dataAccess;

        public CustomerProvider(IDaoFactory dalFactory)
        {
            this.dataAccess = dalFactory;
        }

        public IEnumerable<BusinessObjects.Customers> GetAllCustomers()
        {
            IList<BusinessObjects.Customers> customerCollection = new List<BusinessObjects.Customers>();
            dataAccess.CustomerDao.GetAllCustomers();
            return customerCollection;
        }

        public IEnumerable<BusinessObjects.Customers> GetCustomertByIds(int[] Ids)
        {
            IList<BusinessObjects.Customers> customerCollection = new List<BusinessObjects.Customers>();
            dataAccess.CustomerDao.GetCustomertByIds(Ids);
            return customerCollection;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First off, get rid of that override.  In fact, that might be your only problem.  You only want to override that if you are directly controlling the model.  Also, you should learn about how to ovrerride virtual methods and why you should (usually) call the base implementation within the override.

Comment: If removing the override to `OnModelCreating` does not fix the exception please include the model for type `Customer` in the question.

Comment: Overriding [OnModelCreating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx) is fine, and exactly what it is there for.

Answer (score 0):

Please show us the definition for CustomerOrder.BusinessObjects.Customer

Do you have any ICollections in there? If so, instantiate them in the constructor or in the property like so:

```
public ICollection<Order> Orders{ get; set; } = new List<Order>();
```

Comment: I have updated the post with CustomerOrder.BusinessObjects.Customer. Shall try what you have recommended

Comment: Well, that's probably not it, since I can't see any collection in there. Now, one question though: I assume CustomerOrder.BusinessObjects.Customer is a different Customer type than the one you are mapping to the database? If so, please give us that definition as well. If not, you don't need the linq select statement in your data fetch.

Comment: I have updated the customer class from the context. This is auto generated class by the entity framework. Not sure why I can see orders in it it

Comment: You can see orders in it because of this 
public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
Now, I see in the constructor that it initializes it just fine, so no issue there.

However, I would advise against all the "virtual" stuff, and switch off lazy loading in the constructor of the context by adding

this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

to it. Not saying it will solve the issue, but you just don't want all that lazy loading mess going on. Who knows it may solve it, but if it doesn't, I would really have to dive in code myself :-D kind of working at the moment :p

Comment: So I put the lazyloading line in the contructor. Updated the post accordingly.  It dosent work. Just to be clear the Icollection line need not be set in the business object class right ?

Comment: @Tom ICollection<Order> doesnt not need to be in your business object class customer (your DTO I assume), unless you are planning to map your orders to your DTO.

Comment: 12seconds: true, but the code generator put that in there. Let's not confuse things further.

Tom: so your error shows up when you hover over return (from customer in customerOrderContext.Customers in the CustomerDoa class, right?

Comment: What does this do for you:

using (var customerOrderContext = new Entities())
            {
                var customers =  customerOrderContext.Customers.ToList()
               ................
            }

So just getting a list of all customers, straight from the context, no linq projection or anything. Does that line execute?

Comment: You are right Tom, The error shows up only when I hover over  return (from customer in customerOrderContext.Customers  in the CustomerDoa class. Especially when I check to see the  customerOrderContext object.The Lines below execute without any error. When I check the count of what the object is returning , it shows zero

Comment: Just to give you additional information I am using dependency injection in all the layers

Comment: As you should ;) and don't let me see you do otherwise! :-D
Just to get some more info, does the "   var customers = customerOrderContext.Customers.ToList();   " line execute? What I find really strange is that you say you get the error when hovering over the customerOrderContext variable, which is your context. Meaning that would not instantiate.. Although all the rest executes? That's really weird...

Comment: Yes this is actually quite hard for us to debug without the solution. I created a dummy project replicated as close as possible to your code based on your question here (with exception of Dependency Injection since I dont know how you set it up or what you use) and I am unable to get that error.

Comment: I have updated the post relevant to Dependency injection.

Comment: Another thing that I have noticed is that when I check the database connection in the context object. I see the following error ServerVersion = '((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)customerOrderContext._database.Connection).ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: <add name="Entities" connectionString="Data Source=Tom-PC\MSSQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=CustomerData;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to return an IEnumerable of an anonymous type, not an
`CustomerOrder.BusinessObjects.Customer` object, otherwise why don't you use

```
IEnumerable<CustomerOrder.BusinessObjects.Customer> ICustomerDao.GetAllCustomers()
        {
            using (var customerOrderContext = new Entities())
            {
                return (from customer in customerOrderContext.Customers

                        select customer).ToList();
            }
        }
```

try to make the method static if this doesn't fix the error.